# Cluster backup error in postgresql 9.6.2

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to take a cluster backup of my localhost but throwing an exception like below.

Currently using postgres 9.6.2

```
pg_basebackup -U repuser -h localhost -D backup -Ft -z -P
```

Error message:

> pg_basebackup: unsupported server version 9.6.2

Can anyone suggest me to resolve.

Comment: You are using an old `pg_basebackup` version - the command line is probably picking up an old installation that is still in the `PATH`. What does `pg_basebackup --version` show you?

Comment: Its showing old version pg_basebackup (PostgreSQL) 9.2.20. so hot to resolve this

Comment: Install the new version

Comment: can you please share me the links to install pg_basebackup. Actually am using postgres 9.6.2

Comment: `pg_basebackup` is part of the regular Postgres installation. You either need to remove the 9.2 installation or change your `PATH` if you have 9.6 installed

Answer (score 0):

If you have mlocate installed, run `locate pg_basebackup`, if not run `find / -name pg_basebackup`. It will give you the list of binaries you have, like:

```
-bash-4.2$ locate pg_basebackup
/usr/bin/pg_basebackup93
/usr/lib64/pgsql93/bin/pg_basebackup
/home/pg/9.1/bin/pg_basebackup
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/pg_basebackup-9.3.mo
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/pg_basebackup-9.3.mo
```

then run `pg_basebackup` with full path, like:

```
/usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_basebackup -U repuser -h localhost -D backup -Ft -z -P
```